# Add Data with Android to MySQL using PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a MySQL Database and I want to add an Entry with my Android App. For this I have a PHP Script in the middle. So my Android app should run the script with the value which shall be inserted into the Database and the Script calls the Database to insert it.
My MySQL Database named `GCM_ID` has just one column named `GCM_ID` and looks like this:

```
GCM_ID
------
id1
id2
id3
...
```

This is my PHP Script:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("my_domain","my_user","my_password");
    mysql_select_db("GCM_ID");

    $id=$_REQUEST['GCM_ID'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into GCM_ID(GCM_ID) VALUES('$id')",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The domain, user and password are correct, I tested this already with another Script.

This is the Java Code of my Android app to connect to the PHP Script:

```
public void insert(String gcm_id) {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GCM_ID", gcm_id));


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("link/to/my/php/script");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

        if (code == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I got the code snippet from [here](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php) and modified the PHP Script and Android code a bit.
When I run my app, I got this error:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a2161963/public_html/insertGcmIds.php on line 9
Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a2161963/public_html/insertGcmIds.php on line 16
```

I'm new to PHP, thats why I don't 
The first problem is see is that the tutorial with the code snippet added a Pair of Values to the MySQL Database and thats why he used an `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`. Can I use this `NameValuePair` with just one Value? Can I do it somehow else?
Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You should cease using the **mysql_*** functions, and immediately begin using **PDO** or **mysqli_*** functions as the 'mysql_*' functions are deprecated.  Since you're new to PHP, there really is no reason for you to learn the older **mysql_*** functions unless you plan on having to support legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $con from mysql_query and mysql_close it will work

```
  mysql_connect("my_domain","my_user","my_password");
    mysql_select_db("GCM_ID");

    $id=$_REQUEST['GCM_ID'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into GCM_ID(GCM_ID) VALUES('$id')"))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    echo json_encode($flag);
    mysql_close();
```

And stop using mysql_ extensions as it is deprecated.... Instead use mysqli or pdo. Try w3schools.com for mysqli extensions.